# why is it a good practice to send Messages in the form of a class in Akka.net?

Tags: c#, akka.net

im new to Akka.net, I was reading this tutorial in [Akka.net bootcamp](https://github.com/revoltez/akka-bootcamp/blob/master/src/Unit-1/lesson2/README.md) and it says that you can send any type of to an Acotr which is great but it also says that it is a good practice to encapsulate the message in a class for example :

Actor 1 wants to Request an information that Actor 2 have (lets say an integer for the sake of simplicity ) , from what i understood from the bootcamp Actor 2 has to respond in the following way

```
Actor2: ReceiveActor{

    int info =5;
    public Actor2(){

    Recieve<Request>(request => sender.Tell(new Response(this.info)); 

   }

public class Response
{
    int Info {get;}
    public Response(int info){
            
       Info = info;
  }

}

}
```

why is this a good practice ?

Comment: Probably because it gives meaning to the data, when used with a property name that's a bit more meaningful than "Info", for example, you surely could send an array of `"John", 27, true` - I guess that's a Person, called John, age 27, and some boolean I don't know what. Maybe isMale? No, wait.. there's the whole gender neutrality thing, gender ought to be freetext these days. How about canDrive?.. Or is it a bible reference, and what the heck is that boolean anyway? If it was all wrapped up in a class that made the data make sense, then it would be more than just data; it would be *information*

Comment: @CaiusJard aaaah okey okey now it makes more sense ,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because all messages have to be immutable, that class with private setter helps you to make immutable because you set all properties values only at construction. Akka needs immutable messages to guarantee operations like routing or sharding.

Comment: that is exactly what i wanted to know , could you please elaborate more on immutability,i mean could you please give me a case where immutability is not guaranteed ?

Comment: The main reason is because you can send the same message to any actos and keep a health state in yur platfom. Here you have an interesting read, it is nice when you start with akka: https://petabridge.com/blog/top-7-akkadotnet-stumbling-blocks